# Extending Publish button using Alchemy webstore in Tridion

Tags: cme, a4t

We are using alchemy webstore in Tridion. 
When the publish button is clicked, we would like to show custom pop-up containing custom functionality. 
This custom pop up should be displayed before the actual pop-up with publishing target loads.

We have gone through few samples, where the functionality is extended using a new icon, but our requirement is to extend the existing publish button using alchemy webstore.

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question :) As it stands, the implied question ("how would we do this") is pretty general - which doesn't make for a great question and answer. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you have tried, what exactly the problems are that you've run into, and try to keep the question as specific as possible?